# Javadoc for Android project in Eclipse gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, javadoc

I am trying to generate JavaDoc comments in Eclipse for my Android Project, but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`. The problem occurs only when I try to generate JavaDocs for classes that import the Android Compatibility Library (`android.support`), which I have attached as an external jar. I also reference Android 2.2 and several Library Projects, but those do not cause this error on their own.

```
C:\Users\workspace\fm\src\com\fm\camera\UploadSubmissionSubmitPhotoVideo.java:9: package android.content does not exist

import android.content.Intent;
                      ^
Standard Doclet version 1.6.0_19
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.TypeMaker.getType(TypeMaker.java:29)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.ClassDocImpl.superclassType(ClassDocImpl.java:441)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:386)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.Util.getAllInterfaces(Util.java:424)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.processType(ClassTree.java:162)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.buildTree(ClassTree.java:114)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.ClassTree.<init>(ClassTree.java:73)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration(AbstractDoclet.java:104)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractDoclet.java:64)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:42)
    at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:269)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:143)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:340)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:128)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:41)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:31)
100 warnings
```

Comment: Can you post the exact StackTrace of the error?

Comment: see i have edit and post the error please see

Comment: @JayThakkar: next time please *add* the stack trace as opposed *replacing* the entire question with the stack trace ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello I Found the solution to this question just you have to do 2 steps :

(1) : Generate a javadoc.xml (create a new txt > save it as javadoc.xml)

(2) : In Run > cmd > and go where you have saved your javadoc file fire a command like this : **ant -f javadoc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project basedir="C:\Users\workspace\fm\src\com\fm\APIClient" default="doc" name="api docs">
<target name="doc" description="my docs">
<javadoc destdir="C:\Users\workspace\fm\doc" doctitle="Testing the Title" verbose="on" 
    use="true" 
    classpath="F:\android SDK and eclipse\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-10\android.jar;C:\Users\workspace\fm\libs

\android-query-full.0.22.10.jar;C:\Users\workspace\fm\libs\commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\workspace\fm\libs\gcm.jar;C:\Users\workspace\fm\libs\httpmime-4.1.jar;F:\android SDK and eclipse\android-sdk-windows\add-ons

\addon_google_apis_google_inc_8\libs\maps.jar"  
    sourcepath="C:\Users\workspace\fm\src;C:\Users\workspace\fm\gen"
    packagenames="com.fm.APIClient" 
    linkoffline="http://d.android.com/reference F:\android SDK and eclipse\android-sdk-windows\docs\reference"
    stylesheetfile="F:\android SDK and eclipse\android-sdk-windows\docs\assets\android-developer-docs.css"
    >
</javadoc>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: This was useful to me, I just had to add the absolute path to the Android library in my classpath then ran ant from the command line as stated above. eg. "/home/name/android-sdks/platforms/android-17/android.jar;libs/android-support-v4.jar"

Comment: @toddles_fp yes throught this command we can easily get the document generated as in eclipse there are so many errors